# How to find out who is receiving files or cancel old transfers in Skype?

Tags: skype, file-transfer

Every once in a while I hear the sound "file received" in Skype. I haven't sent any files recently but there are probably files I sent earlier to group chats and it's probably some members of group chats receiving files sent weeks ago. Is there a way to find out who is receiving these files? Or at least cancel old file transfers without erasing history every time?

Answer (score 2):

In Skype go to View → Files Sent and Received and check all the files that you have send and received. you can cancel them as well.

Comment: How do I cancel them from that list? There is also no way to see who is receiving files.